# Directory write permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions

Let's say that i created directory (called temp) in my ~ and inside it i have created few files.
Now, my umask is 0002 but for the sake of exercise i changed permissions on ~/temp/:

```
chmod 222 temp
```

As far as i know, having write privileges for a directory would mean that i cannot open it or read it's content, but i should be able to add a file (or remove a file) inside. For example, i thought that this would work just fine :

```
touch temp/new_file.txt
```

However, when i try to do this, it just throws an error:

```
touch: cannot touch 'temp/new_file.txt': Permission denied
```

I couldn't find out why this doesn't work the way i expected, so i am wondering what CAN i do with directory when i have only write permissions and why creating a new file the way i tried doesn't work?

(All of the commands above were executed in ~)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Permissions work differently for directories,

This is not a perfect explanation but,

According to the manual page of chmod (`man chmod`):

> The  letters  rwxXst select file mode bits for the affected users:
> read
> (r), write (w), **execute (or search for directories) (x)**, execute/search
> only  if  the file is a directory or already has execute permission for
> some user (X), set user or group ID on execution (s), restricted  dele‐
> tion  flag or sticky bit (t).  Instead of one or more of these letters,
> you can specify exactly one of the letters ugo: the permissions granted
> to  the  user  who  owns the file (u), the permissions granted to other
> users who are members of the file's  group  (g),  and  the  permissions
> granted  to  users  that are in neither of the two preceding categories
> (o).

Which means to write to a file inside a directory you need to first **change into the directory (execute permission)** and create a file (write permission)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So i need to have execute permission on my directory in order to be able to enter it and then create a file inside, but, if that's so, then what CAN i do with directory when i have write permission, i mean, what's difference between having no permissions at all (no read, no write, no execute) and having only write permissions (with no read and no execute)?